# Firestore: react render component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I wirtten a small code where I fetch the size of a collection in firestore and then I will render a component in a for-loop. When I put a number in the for loop it works well. But when I try to put the size in it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Title from './comonents/Title'
import Player from './comonents/Player'
import RoundTest from './comonents/RundeTest'

import db from './FirestoreConfig';


class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    db.collection('player').get().then(snap => {
      size = snap.size
      console.log(size);
    })
  }

  createRunde = () => {
    let runde = []
    // 5 is here the number 
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      runde.push(<div id="runde"><RoundTest rundeComp={i}/></div>)
    }
    return runde
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="APP">
        <div id="title">
          <Title/>
        </div>
        <div id="player">
          <Player/>
        </div>

        <div id="runderoot">
          {this.createRunde()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Have someone an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some scope issues. Since you want to update the render based on size, it’s best to store the size in state and call setState once you fetch the snapshot.